# Help with a point of sale design

Tags: database-design

I've not designed a point of sale before and frankly, don't have much knowledge of what attributes are needed. I found a design and realized that it still won't store everything I need. I'm still missing some attributes.

Some of the issues that I see with this digram:

- I need to allow for product returns.
- I need to allow no charge items. (Free)
- There should be an allowable discount for each product and also an additional discount that can be applied at check out.
- The pos_invoice table doesn't have a total attribute.
- How to handle voided transactions...

I think I can add a total column to the invoice table but I'm wondering why it wasn't there to begin with. So where should these attributes go?

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here to handle the bulleted items above?

---

I have an an image that I want to show but unfortunately, I need 10 rep points to do this which I don't have. Maybe after a small discussion I will have earned these points to upload the image.

Comment: It seems that you're asking for an essay on creating a POS system. Could you try to rephrase your question? What programming language are you using? What database system are you using? What is your current database structure? Etc.

Comment: Bob, with all due respect, I don't see what my programming language has to do with this. We're talking about a database design here. The database will be MySQL but that isn't written in stone at this point. I have an image of the table structures but can't upload it yet because I don't have enough "rep points" to do that.

Comment: perhaps a starting point might be http://www.databaseanswers.com/data_models/

Comment: Fair enough. I've voted your question up so hopefully you can get more permissions soon. Also, can't you post links? You could upload the image to e.g. http://imgur.com/ and link to it.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to or cannot create new tables and logic in the design you found:

•I need to allow for product returns.

Product returns could be treated as a purchase  using the customer as a supplier and matching the price and shipping or duplicate the sales related table and call it returns.  Adjust the accounting system to apply the total from the returns as a credit instead of a debit.

•I need to allow no charge items. (Free)

•There should be an allowable discount for each product and also an additional discount that can be applied at check out.

Does your template system support cupons?  If not add an item in inventory which does not have a price and alow the price to be adjusted during the sales approval process.
Do not change the price for an item but include a discount of 100%

•The pos_invoice table doesn't have a total attribute.

Totals are calculated and do not need to be stored in the DB but sometimes are for speed. (reading only sales header table insted of calculating from sales detail records.

•How to handle voided transactions...

Most POS system employe some type of authorization prior to shipping.  Does you template POS have an authorization system?  If so add a decline reason of "Void".

**OR**

Contract with one of the web hosting sites and use their shopping cart feature which does everything you want and more.